# Using SQL, how to check if files with a particular name exist?

Tags: sql, command-line

I'm looking for the way to find if particular files exist in the folder using sql.

I have the following files:
`ABC.DEF.T123.A001.txt`
`ABC.DEF.T456.A002.txt`
`ABC.DEF.T789.A003.txt`

I'm using below logic to find if file `A001` exist

```
declare @fullPath varchar(200) = '\\mypath\filepath\'
declare @fileName varchar(200) = 'ABC.DEF.*.A001.txt'

EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @fullPath, @exist OUTPUT
SET @exist = CAST(@exist AS BIT)

select @exist
```

When displaying the value of @exist, I always get 0, even though, the file containing `A002` sequence exists.

I think I'm not using the filter the right way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Double check permissions on your file. Right click on it, go to "Give Access" -> "Specific People" -> then select "Everyone"

Answer (score 1):

Permissions could be blocking access to the directory....

When you use Windows explorer, it is using your credentials to access the directory/files, while Sql Server will use the credentials that is running the service... which might or not have access to the file share.

If you’re able to access that file path by virtue of your domain account, Sql Server must be run using a domain account with permission to that file share instead of the default ‘Network Service’ account.

Answer (score 0):

declare @File_Exists INT

EXEC xp_fileexist '\mypath\filepath\ABC.DEF.*.A001.txt', @File_Exists OUT
Select @File_Exists

Returns a 1 if the file exists or a 0 if it does not exits. To use this code on a SQL server the user must have the correct permissions and should be the admin on the server. This isn't the safest solution - there are many services you could use that would be a lot more secure than this.

Comment: But, that's what I have and I get 0, even though file A002 exists

Comment: Most likely means the code isn't executing properly because you don't have the correct permissions on the SQL server.

Comment: Permissions arr fine. It works in other cases when I do not have to use wildcard

Answer (score 0):

We do this when checking a table that is storing files and you want to audit to confirm the file is there.  You have to do some type of loop as the 
 master.dbo.xp_fileexist 
requires the full path so folder + filename

here is a quick loop to do this

declare @exist as int
    declare @fullPath varchar(200) 
    Declare @j as int = 0 
    Declare @Mj as int = (Select COUNT(File_name) FROM table where you have filenames and paths )

```
WHILE @j < @mj BEGIN
Set @j = @j+1
    Set @fullPath = (
        Select top 1 Folder+fname as photo 
        FROM (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over(order by Fname) RN FROM dbo.TABLE_with_files) A
        WHERE RN=@j ) 

    EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @fullPath, @exist OUTPUT
    SET @exist = CAST(@exist AS BIT)
    if @exist = 0 BEGIN
        select * FROM dbo.TABLE_with_Files where Folder+fname = @fullPath collate database_Default

    END 


END -- while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions to the folder are ok then I wouldn't use wildcard.
In order to use wildcard I would print all files in a table and search there for the file that I want to find.

Try to adapt to your code like the following

```
DECLARE @FilesExist  INT = 0
       ,@BasePath VARCHAR(100) = '%Path to the folder+\%'

DECLARE @Files TABLE ([FileName] VARCHAR(100), Depth INT, [File] INT) 

INSERT INTO @Files
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @BasePath,1,1;


SELECT TOP 1 @FilesExist = 1
FROM @Files
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM @Files
               WHERE [FileName] LIKE '%yourFileNameUsingWildcardsOrNot%')
OR EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
               FROM @Files
               WHERE [FileName] LIKE '%yourFileName2UsingWildcardsOrNot%')

               
SELECT @FilesExist
```

Based on the flag you can decide your flow next
I hope it helped.